# Certificate does not contain a private key when importing certificate

Tags: certificate, sharepoint, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I'm following the following tutorial [Configuring SharePoint 2010 and ADFS v2 End to End](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/30/configuring-sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-v2-end-to-end.aspx)
Because i want to use a single sign on between my sharepoint and crm 2011.

I have a sharepoint server, a crm server and an SQL server with ad fs 2.0.

When following the tutorial mentioned above. I come at the instruction to export the certificate used by adfs to sign the tokens it sends out.

> "ADFS uses a certificate to sign the tokens it sends out."

But when i look at my certificate,

> "... but there will always be ONLY one Primary token signing certificate.  Click on that certificate, and then click on the View Certificate link in the right pane."
>   Blockquote

then i see that my certificate don't contains a private key. I first didn't notice the difference between the screenshot in the tutorial and what i could see on my screen. But when i tried to import my certificate to the sharepoint server, i got an error saying that the certificate does not contain a private key.

How should i solve this problem? I'm trying for a long time to get this set up but every time something else goes wrong. I hope i can finish this soon with maybe a little help here on SO ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADFS uses three certificates:

- The service communications key (normally the one used by IIS for SSL)
- Token decrypting
- Token signing

Only the first has a private key. The other two are created when you install ADFS.

If you look at the tutorial, you'll see:

"In this particular case I chose to use the certificate I created for SSL on the ADFS web site.  I’m not suggesting that this is needed or even recommend; it’s just what I chose to do.  Now that you are viewing the certificate, click on the Details tab at the top of the dialog."

So what you need to do is add a token-signing certificate and choose for this purpose the SSL certificate. That way you will have a private key.

Or create your own (I use [SelfSSL7](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2011/02/wif-self-signed-certificates.html)) and use that. Note : Not in Production!

Refer: [AD FS 2.0: How to Replace the SSL, Service Communications, Token-Signing, and Token-Decrypting Certificates](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2554.aspx)

Comment: 5 star answer! Thank you! I thought i maybe could do this but i was not sure. And i did not want to continue the tutorial without knowing if i did one step good or wrong. I hope i can continue to the end now :)

Comment: Ok, i'm having other problem now with certificate. When i try to select my certificate in the "edit bindings" section in IIS i get the following warning: 
---------------------------
Edit Site Binding
---------------------------
One or more intermediate certificates in the certificate chain are missing.  To resolve this issue, make sure that all of the intermediate certificates are installed. For more information, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954755. I've followed the instruction on that website but still no success. Do you know more about this too?

Comment: Not really. Do you have the intermediate certificates? e.g. see here : http://www.aip.im/2010/12/error-in-iis-when-adding-secure-binding-because-intermediate-certificate-is-missing/